# How can I update and iterate the sub maps and update map into different location of map at the same time in clojure

Tags: clojure

I've below clojure object.

```
{:openapi "3.0.3",
 :info {:title "Swagger API", :version "0.0.1"},
 :paths
 {"/api"
  {:post
   {:parameters
    [{:in "query",
      :name "x",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
     {:in "query",
      :name "y",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
     {:in "header",
      :name "Content-Type",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema
      {:type "string",
       :enum ["application/json" "application/xml" "application/edn"]}}
     {:in "header",
      :name "Accept",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "string"}}],
    :requestBody
    {:content
     {:application/json
      {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Body15899"}}}},
    :responses
    {:200
     {:description "ok",
      :content
      {:application/json
       {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Tag"}}}},
     :400
     {:description "ok",
      :content
      {:application/json
       {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/FatalError"}}}}}}}},
 :components
 {:schemas
  {:Body15899
   {:type "object",
    :properties {:foo {:type "string"}},
    :additionalProperties false,
    :required ["foo"]},
   :FatalError
   {:type "object",
    :properties
    {:id {:type "string"},
     :description {:type "string"},
     :code {:type "string"}},
    :additionalProperties false,
    :required ["id" "description" "code"]},
   :Tag
   {:type "object",
    :properties
    {:id
     {:description "Unique identifier for the tag",
      :type "integer",
      :format "int64"},
     :name {:description "Friendly name for the tag"}},
    :additionalProperties false}}}}
```

I need to move [:paths   :requestBody] to [:components :requestBodies] and [:paths   :responses ] to [:components responses]0.0.1
When I do that I need to other objects [:paths   :parameters] intact. I need to do this for all endpoints.
like so the above the object should result into below -

```
{:openapi "3.0.3",
 :info {:title "Swagger API", :version "0.0.1"},
 :paths
 {"/api"
  {:post
   {:parameters
    [{:in "query",
      :name "x",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
     {:in "query",
      :name "y",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
     {:in "header",
      :name "Content-Type",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema
      {:type "string",
       :enum ["application/json" "application/xml" "application/edn"]}}
     {:in "header",
      :name "Accept",
      :description "",
      :required true,
      :schema {:type "string"}}],
    :requestBody
    {:$ref "#/components/responses/Tag"},
    :responses
    {200
     {:$ref "#/components/responses/Tag"},
     400
     {:$ref "#/components/responses/FatalError"}}}}},
 :components
 {:schemas
  {"Body15830"
   {:type "object",
    :properties {:foo {:type "string"}},
    :additionalProperties false,
    :required [:foo]},
   "FatalError"
   {:type "object",
    :properties
    {:id {:type "string"},
     :description {:type "string"},
     :code {:type "string"}},
    :additionalProperties false,
    :required [:id :description :code]},
   "Tag"
   {:type "object",
    :properties
    {:id
     {:description "Unique identifier for the tag",
      :type "integer",
      :format "int64"},
     :name {:description "Friendly name for the tag"}},
    :additionalProperties false}}}
   :responses 
   {"Tag"
    {:description "ok",
     :content
     {"application/json"
      {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Tag"}}}}
    "FatalError"
    {:description "ok",
     :content
     {"application/json"
      {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/FatalError"}}}}}
   :requestBodies
   {"Body15830"
    {:content
     {"application/json"
      {:name "Body15830",
       :schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Body15830"}}}}}
    }
```

Below is the clojure code I wrote.

```clj
(defn get-response-ref [v]
  (some-> (-> v
              :content
              vals
              first
              :schema
              :$ref)
          (str/replace "/schemas/" "/responses/")))

(defn endpoint-processor2 [endpoint]
  (let [backup (reduce-kv (fn [acc method definition]
                            (let [body-acc      (if (:requestBody definition)
                                                  (-> acc
                                                      (update-in [:requestBodySchemas] conj (:requestBody definition))
                                                      (update-in [:requestBodyDefinitions method] conj (str "#components/requestBodies/" (-> (get-in definition [:requestBody :content])
                                                                                                                                             vals
                                                                                                                                             first
                                                                                                                                             :name)))) acc)
                                  responses-acc (reduce-kv (fn [acc-res k v]
                                                             (clojure.pprint/pprint v)
                                                             (-> acc-res
                                                                 (update-in [:responses method k] conj (get-response-ref v))
                                                                 (update-in [:responses-schema] conj v))) body-acc (:responses definition))]
                              responses-acc))
                          {} endpoint)]
    backup))
```

when I call the above code with `(endpoint-processor2 (get-in oa [:paths "/api"]))` I get below response ->

```clj
(def oa {:openapi "3.0.3",
         :info {:title "Swagger API", :version "0.0.1"},
         :paths
         {"/api"
          {:post
           {:parameters
            [{:in "query",
              :name "x",
              :description "",
              :required true,
              :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
             {:in "query",
              :name "y",
              :description "",
              :required true,
              :schema {:type "integer", :format "int64"}}
             {:in "header",
              :name "Content-Type",
              :description "",
              :required true,
              :schema
              {:type "string",
               :enum ["application/json" "application/xml" "application/edn"]}}
             {:in "header",
              :name "Accept",
              :description "",
              :required true,
              :schema {:type "string"}}],
            :requestBody
            {:content
             {:application/json
              {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Body15899"}}}},
            :responses
            {:200
             {:description "ok",
              :content
              {:application/json
               {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Tag"}}}},
             :400
             {:description "ok",
              :content
              {:application/json
               {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/FatalError"}}}}}}}},
         :components
         {:schemas
          {:Body15899
           {:type "object",
            :properties {:foo {:type "string"}},
            :additionalProperties false,
            :required ["foo"]},
           :FatalError
           {:type "object",
            :properties
            {:id {:type "string"},
             :description {:type "string"},
             :code {:type "string"}},
            :additionalProperties false,
            :required ["id" "description" "code"]},
           :Tag
           {:type "object",
            :properties
            {:id
             {:description "Unique identifier for the tag",
              :type "integer",
              :format "int64"},
             :name {:description "Friendly name for the tag"}},
            :additionalProperties false}}}})

(endpoint-processor2 (get-in ao [:paths "/api"]))
```

I get below response -

```
{:requestBodySchemas ({:content {:application/json {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Body15899"}}}}),
 :requestBodyDefinitions {:post ("#components/requestBodies/")},
 :responses {:post {:200 ("#/components/responses/Tag"), :400 ("#/components/responses/FatalError")}},
 :responses-schema ({:description "ok",
                     :content {:application/json {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/FatalError"}}}}
                    {:description "ok", :content {:application/json {:schema {:$ref "#/components/schemas/Tag"}}}})}
```

I don't know how can I merge accordingly in the respective $ref component locations.
I'm new to clojure. How can I achieve the same.

Comment: Your in and out data samples don't correspond to the problem description.

Comment: The samples are also much more complicated than necessary to demonstrate the problem. Simplify the input and output so that they contain only the essence of what you're having trouble with, not a bunch of extra features.